# JavaScript to determine Salesforce1 location (native app or mobile browser)

Tags: javascript, salesforce1-app

I've found that I need some different behaviors based on whether the user is visiting my VisualForce page via the Salesforce1 native app (iOS or Android) or is using a mobile browser on the /one/one.app URL.  I've seen answers for testing `sforce.one` to determine if the user is on Salesforce1, but this doesn't help for native vs. mobile web.

[This post](http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.com/2014/01/visualforce-in-salesforce1.html) mentioned testing for `SalesforceTouchContainer` in the user agent string.  I'm not actually seeing that work, but the following JavaScript does seem to work properly for me on both Android and iOS:

```
<script>
var isSalesforceNative = (window.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('salesforce1') != -1);
</script>
```

It works, but it feels hacky to me.  Does anyone have a better suggestion on how to do this, or is user agent sniffing really the only way?

Comment: There is no supported way, so anything you do is a hack. I think what you've done here is okay.

Comment: wouldn't testing window.top.location.href for '/one/one.app' work? Or is that URL the same for both native and mobile browser?

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
// Check to see if the device has geolocation 
// detection capabilities with JavaScript
var lat, lon;
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        function(position){
        lat = position.coords.latitude;
        lon = position.coords.longitude;
```

Comment: Mobile browser and native app might both have geolocation enabled...